# How to get all meetups I've been to

Tags: meetup

On [Meetup](http://meetup.com), how can I get a list of meetups I have attended in the past?

Those meetups are the past ones for which I have RSVPed with *YES*.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found if I go to:

Calender> I'm Going

you can scroll through monthly and see what events you RSVP'd "yes" to.

I then went through the events I attended and tagged myself in photos so on my profile I had photos of events I attended.

Comment: This is great and still valid. However a bit tedious when I have attended several hundred over the last 5 or so years of Meetups.

Answer (score 5):

To do this, you'll most likely need to use the meetup.com API (I wasn't able to find a way to do it directly through the site).

Here is the documentation for using the API's activity feed feature:

http://www.meetup.com/meetup_api/docs/activity/

And here is an example of how to get the activity feed for a user:

http://www.meetup.com/meetup_api/console/?path=/activity

To do this, you'll need an API key (Meetup automatically gave me one when I entered the API site) as well as your user ID (found on the Account > General tab).

Basically, this returns a JSON response listing all of a user's activity. RSVP's will take the form "rsvp_response": "Yes", and the event name will look something like "event_name": "August 2013 Civic Hacknight II",

I'll leave how to parse this up to you, but the basics of how many events you've attended and what they were called will all be in this API response. Here's a good overview if you are unfamiliar with working with JSON:

http://www.copterlabs.com/blog/json-what-it-is-how-it-works-how-to-use-it/

Or, you could always search for "rsvp_response": "Yes" in the JSON document and simply copy and paste.

Answer (score 4):

Goto the homepage: www.meetup.com, click Calendar tab, and then choose: I'm going

Or use this link:

http://www.meetup.com/find/events/?allMeetups=true&eventFilter=going

Answer (score 0):

You should have automatic emails generated every time you RSVP to a meetup. If you are using gmail simply search from: meetup, subject: you're confirmed and you will get a list of meetups you have RSVPed for. If gmail has archived your old mail then do the search in:anywhere

Hope this is a simple solution

Comment: I get an email confirmation as soon as I RSVP. If you turned off that setting you wont get it. Additionally if the event was cancelled or you backed out this wont show you that.

Answer (score -2):

I just did an email search for "See you at" which worked for me in gathering all the meetups I've attended over the years.